# Rails not redirecting after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am learning rails via Hartl's tutorial, but I can get  chapter 9.2.3 [Link](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#top) to work

Everything before this section was working perfectly before this section, but after getting here, if I access /users/1/edit and login with a different or same user, it redirects back to the user page and not to the edit page.

sessions helper:

```
def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
end

def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
end
```

users controller methods for before_filter

```
private

def signed_in_user
  unless signed_in?
    store_location
    redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in."
  end
end

def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
end
```

before filters in user controller

```
before_filter :signed_in_user,only:[:edit,:update,:index]
before_filter :correct_user, only:[:edit,:update]
```

My code so far [Github](https://github.com/Ommy/sample_app)

Comment: looked through your code and looks identical to mine, will have a peek at your rep

Comment: .... strange. looking further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed calling redirect_back_or user instead of redirect_to in SessionsController create:

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in user
        redirect_back_or user
      else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
        render 'new'
      end
  end
```

I found out by adding the session to the debug info at the bottom of the page, and the return_to was still there after successful login:

```
{"session_id"=>"4dcc1baaf651aaab953026902b32f805", "_csrf_token"=>"0YkP+yd/DDuInX4kIBkjwbzxV1GK0oYBDAXEiWnHLGs=", "return_to"=>"/users/1/edit"}
```

Comment: Ah, it seems so. I guess I should spend a little bit more time wrapping my head around this. Thank you.